# Unbalanced addition to ESP otherwise it segfaults

Tags: assembly

I have this code (it does require 16 byte stack alignment - OS: Mac OS X)

```
global  _main
extern _printf

section .data
        hw:  db 'Hello World!' ,0xA,0

section .text
    _main:

    ; esp is 0
    sub esp, 8
    ; esp is -8
    push hw
    ; esp is -12
    ; call makes esp -16
    call _printf
    ; esp is now -8, printf popping its argument and ret taking the address put on by call
    add esp, 8    ; -8 bytes remove padding
    ; esp is now 0
    ; why add an extra 4 bytes???
    add esp, 4
    ; esp is now +4??

    mov eax, 99
    ret
```

However if I do not have the line add esp, 4 it segmentation faults even though it is unbalanced ( I never subtract 4 from esp only 8 which I then add back on).

Comment: @DCoder: Why not write this up as an answer?

Comment: You also got the initial value of esp wrong

Comment: @RaymondChen How do you mean? I know it isn't 0 but that is an nice number to start with. Obviously there are other things on the stack from calling main, is that what you mean?

Comment: What RaymondChen means is that the value of ESP you wrote down is wrong if you view it as an absolute value. The value you wrote is more correctly interpreted as "relative to function entry point".

Comment: _printf() takes one argument here, so you should add esp,4 to pop it back off the stack.  You forgot to take care of the *real* problem, you have to restore the stack frame from the original sub esp,8

Comment: The initial esp is not 16-byte aligned because the "call" instruction pushed a return address. Therefore the initial esp is actually -4(mod 16) not 0 mod 16.

Comment: @HansPassant My understanding was that printf took care of that because it was its arguments.

Comment: @RaymondChen So do I have to add esp, 4 to align it then or would I sub esp, 12 because add would 'erase' the ret address by putting esp back 4 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions that take a variable number of arguments, such as `printf`, cannot "pop" their arguments off the stack, the caller must do it for them. This is because the `ret` instruction only supports constant arguments (*immediates* in Intel lingo), but the number of arguments varies with each call.

See [Wikipedia: Calling conventions with caller cleanup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Caller_clean-up).

Comment: So basically printf can't know am I taking 3 arguments or 1. Because if it is 1 and it pops 3 it will just get garbage or segfault for accessing invalid memory?